# Include URL with city parameter based on user's IP

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

The javascript code below works perfectly in the HTML of my site. It is a geo-target server that shows the city based on the user's IP.

```
<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>
```

What I am doing is and I can not get it to work within a link I want to be generated according to the person's city. Example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=New York">New York</a>
```

I tried to work the way down but the response to the end of the URL after `?Q=` is the code itself. I tried this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>">New York</a>
```

I have no experience with this, so any solution either in PHP or javascript would be welcome. I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery this is quite easy:

```
function cityUrl( ){
var url = "http://www.example.net/?q=";
var city;
$.get("http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip=", function(data){
url += data;
city = data
}
var html = "<a href='" + url + "'>"+city+"</a>";
$( "div" ).append( html );
}
```

This generates a url based on the location, makes a link out of that url and sets the city as the clickable part of the link. Then this will be appended to the element specified (in this case div)

This might need some tweeking for your purposes but im sure you get the idea

---

I believe I was too much unclear about everything so I`ll try to clarify: 
This is a function you need to call once for the page you want to show them on. Of course you **cannot** copy and paste this code and expect it to work.

[Fiddle doesnt 100% work due to https and cross origin requests, but does reflect the idea](https://jsfiddle.net/91puptgf/)

Comment: This code needs to be tweeked before you can use it, will make a fiddle tomorrow bacause now im going to bed

Comment: Updated with a fiddle, the rest you need to figure out for your own specific needs.